# How to parse SMS from GSM modem in c#

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, serial-port, at-command

I'm creating messenger web app. Already did message send method. My message receiving method works with with **SerialDataReceivedEventHandler**
My code :

```
 public class InnerComPortSettings
{
    public static SerialPort SerialPort;

    public static void OpenPort()
    {
        SerialPort = new SerialPort("COM3", 115200)
        {
            Parity = Parity.None,
            DataBits = 8,
            StopBits = StopBits.One,
            Handshake = Handshake.None,
            DtrEnable = true,
            RtsEnable = true
        };

        //Thread.Sleep(1000);
        SerialPort.Open();
    }
}

private string _messageString;

    public Task ReceiveSms()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            InnerComPortSettings.SerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
            InnerComPortSettings.SerialPort.WriteLine("AT+CMGF?\r");

            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            InnerComPortSettings.SerialPort.WriteLine("AT+CNMI=1,2,0,0,0\r");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            InnerComPortSettings.SerialPort.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=0\r");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

        });

    }

    public void DataReceivedHandler(
        object sender,
        SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;         

        _messageString = sp.ReadLine();

        GetPdu();
    }
    }
```

So what i want is to parse only SMS info and message and then store it to database.

```
//Response after start
    AT+CMGF=1
    OK
    AT+CNMI=1,2,0,0,0
    OK

//Response after getting message
    +CMT: "+xxxxxxxxxx",,"18/05/30,10:08:08+18"
    Testing
```

What is the best way to exclude first part and separate second into peaces?

Comment: You can split the text and search for DateTime. No other part of SMS has it. Then you can parse it easily

Comment: If your answer starts with `+CMT` you know what kind of command you receive and how to parse everything that comes after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for better parsing I switched to getting PDU from modem, checking for PDU with regex and after parsing PDU into parts.
**Changed CMGF to 0**

```
AT+CMGF=0
OK
AT+CNMI=1,2,0,0,0
OK
```

**Checking Serial port response for PDU**

```
 public void GetPdu()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_messageString);

        Regex regex = new Regex("^([0-9A-F]+\r)$");
        Match match = regex.Match(_messageString);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Match: " + match.Value);
            string messagePdu = match.Value;
            ParseMessage(messagePdu);
        }
    }
```

**Method for decoding** For this method I used this [Source](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15924/Library-for-Decode-Encode-SMS-PDU)

```
ublic void ParseMessage(string messagePdu)
    {
        SMSType smsType = SmsBase.GetSMSType(messagePdu);
        switch (smsType)
        {
            case SMSType.SMS:
                Sms sms = new Sms();
                Sms.Fetch(sms, ref messagePdu);

                string messageBody = sms.Message;
                string phoneNumber = sms.PhoneNumber;
                DateTime messageDateTime = DateTime.Parse(sms.ServiceCenterTimeStamp.ToString());
                string state = "Received";
                SaveMessage(messageBody, phoneNumber, messageDateTime, state);

                break;
            case SMSType.StatusReport:
                SmsStatusReport statusReport = new SmsStatusReport();
                SmsStatusReport.Fetch(statusReport, ref messagePdu);
                break;
        }          
    }
```